# updating the files that are deployed on ec2-instance

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

I am new to laravel and AWS. I have created a website in laravel and deployed it in ec2-instance. I want to make some bug fixes in the files. How can I make those changes on the existing EC2 instance??

Comment: That depends on how you deployed it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than SSH into your instance, do you have something like WinSCP which is an FTP app I use for my AWS instances. If not, install WinSCP (or equivalent), add your ppk file for authentication, and you should be good to go.

Also - just ensure you have the correct folder permissions in your code folder. If not - you'll need to SSH in and fix that, as you'll get a permissions error when you try to upload your new files.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to SSH into the EC2 instance.

Here's a link on how to SSH into an EC2 instance:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html